# Loader/Spinner when UICollectionView is loading in Swift

Tags: swift, networking, swift3, uicollectionview, spinner

I created a spinner function which can be launched with a start function and stopped by a stop function (simple aha).

I would like to show the spinner when my UICollection is loading. Indeed, I have to wait maybe 4 seconds with a blank view to get the data from the servers and show images.

I don't really know how I could do this. Is there a native function which know when the data is processing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function call to get data from your server is an asynchronized call with call back closure. So all you need to do is to show your spinner as soon as you request data from the server, and hide the spinner when you have the data back. For example

```
func getData() {
    //Do something here
    showSpinner()
    Alamofire.request("SomeUrl").response { response in
        //process response here
        //reload collection view
        hideSpinner()
    }
}
```